# AJAX HTTP GET request must be fired twice to work

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing an ajax chat program, and I'm having a weird bug. I have to call a GET request twice for it to handle it properly. The first time it's fired it seems to respond fine to the server, however it will not activate the the function assigned to onreadystatechange [ getChatText() ] until the second time it's called. Not sure what's causing it, and I figured you guys could help.

Code posted below.

Javascript:

```
var recieveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
var sendReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
var lastMessage = "NULL";
var mTimer;

//Create XMLHTTP Object
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
};

//GET & POST creation
function getChatText() {
    if (recieveReq.readyState == 4 || recieveReq.readyState == 0) {
        recieveReq.onreadystatechange = handleRecieveChat();
        recieveReq.open("GET", 'chat.php?chat=1', true);
        recieveReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        recieveReq.send(null);
    };
};
function sendChatText() {
    if(document.getElementById('text_message').value == '') {
        alert("You have not entered a message");
        return;
    };
    if (sendReq.readyState == 4 || sendReq.readyState == 0) {
        sendReq.onreadystatechange = handleSendChat();
        sendReq.open("POST", 'chat.php?send=1', true);
        sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var param = '&message=' + document.getElementById('text_message').value;
        sendReq.send(param);
        document.getElementById('text_message').value = '';
    };
};

//Handle Send & Receive
function handleRecieveChat() {
    if (recieveReq.readyState == 4 && recieveReq.status == 200) {
        var chatDiv = document.getElementById('div_chat');
        var tempResponse = recieveReq.responseText;
        var response = tempResponse.replace(/\\\//g,"/");
        if (response != lastMessage) {
            chatDiv.innerHTML = response;
        };
        chatDiv.scrollTop = chatDiv.scrollHeight;
        lastMessage = response;
        mTimer = setTimeout('getChatText();', 5000);
    };
};
function handleSendChat() {
    clearInterval(mTimer);
    if (sendReq.readyState == 4 || sendReq.readyState == 0) {
        getChatText();
    }
};

function resetChat() {}; //Empty for now

document.onload = getChatText();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" ); 
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" ); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" ); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache" );
    header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

    if (!$connect) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno($connect));
    }

    if(isset($_GET["chat"])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY message_id;";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $time = substr($row['post_time'], 0, 5);
                echo "<span style=color:".$row['user_color'].">".$row['user_name']."</span> (".$time."): ".$row['message']."<br>";
            }
        }
        $connect->close();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != '') {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO message (chat_id, user_id, user_name, message, post_time, user_color) VALUES (1, 3, 'Riley', '".$_POST['message']."', NOW(), '#29D410');";    //Couple are default for testing purposes
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        echo $sql;
        $connect->close();
    }
?>
```

PS: 
Please don't bother with pointing out sql input sanitation or other things I haven't gotten to yet. Just answers for this http request handling bug please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onreadystatechange` is an event handler and as such should be referencing a function. In your code, you're referencing the result of `handleReceiveChat` and `handleSendChat` which are both returning nothing, so`undefined`. Try changing to the following:

`receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleReceiveChat`

`sendReq.onreadystatechange = handleSendChat;`

It will appear as though the call is working the second time, however, the code will be using the response from the first call (as the second response won't have completed yet).